# How to dismiss DraggableScrollableSheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, draggable

I try to make a pop up card when I press on a specific button and I use DraggableScrollableSheet because I want it starts minimized then the user can drag it up to maximize it.
so the question is there some way to dismiss this widget when the user press on the back screen or any other way to dismiss it?

Comment: can you share some code? as far as i know, `DraggableScrollableSheet` can not be dismissed you only have to hide it by checking some condition

Answer (score 0):

I just call pop function inside the onTap callback function of the GestureDetector.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```